# Yii CDbCommandBuilder query

Tags: php, postgresql, join, yii

I'm trying to perform a query in Yii with CDbCommandBuilder so I can have the resultset in an array.

Problem is that I don't understand how to convert my SQL (pgsql) to the Yii CDbCommandBuilder syntax. Mainly my problem is with nested joins.

The query:

```
SELECT  p.id
                up.id as fid,
                sum(CASE
                        WHEN v1.count>v2.count THEN v2.count
                            ELSE v1.count
                        END
                ) as res
        FROM product as v1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT p_id, count
            FROM product
            WHERE user_id = {$user_id}) as v2 on v1.p_id = v2.p_id and v1.user_id <> {$user_id}
        RIGHT JOIN users as p on p.id = v1.user_id
        INNER JOIN uf on uf.friend_id = p.id and uf.user_id = {$user_id} and is_active = true
        INNER JOIN up on up.user_id = p.id and is_active = true
        GROUP BY p.id, up.id
        ORDER BY res desc
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: try: $sql = "...";$params = array(':user_id' => $user_id);
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, $params) and use :user_id instead of {$user_id} in your sql query

Comment: @Juris Malinens, you can post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT  p.id
                up.id as fid,
                sum(CASE
                        WHEN v1.count>v2.count THEN v2.count
                            ELSE v1.count
                        END
                ) as res
        FROM product as v1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT p_id, count
            FROM product
            WHERE user_id = :user_id) as v2 on v1.p_id = v2.p_id and v1.user_id <> :user_id
        RIGHT JOIN users as p on p.id = v1.user_id
        INNER JOIN uf on uf.friend_id = p.id and uf.user_id = :user_id and is_active = true
        INNER JOIN up on up.user_id = p.id and is_active = true
        GROUP BY p.id, up.id
        ORDER BY res desc";

$params = array(':user_id' => $user_id);
$aArrayOfRows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, $params);
```